# Changing selective index dates in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a list of dates:

```
xl_file

                     Day
Date                 
2011-01-26  Wednesday
2011-03-02  Wednesday
2011-04-12    Tuesday
2011-04-14   Thursday
2011-04-22     Friday
              ...
2020-05-25     Monday
2020-10-02     Friday
2020-11-16     Monday
2020-11-30     Monday
2020-12-25     Friday

[144 rows x 1 columns]
```

Of the dates which are listed inside the data frame above, these are the dates which I need to change:

```
list_of_dates

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2018-01-25 00:00:00, 2018-02-22 00:00:00, 2018-04-26 00:00:00, 2018-05-31 00:00:00, 2018-06-28 00:00:00, 2018-07-26 00:00:00, 2018-08-30 00:00:00, 2018-09-27 00:00:00, 2018-10-25 00:00:00, 2018-11-29 00:00:00, 2018-12-27 00:00:00, 2019-01-31 00:00:00, 2019-02-28 00:00:00, 2019-03-28 00:00:00, 2019-04-25 00:00:00, 2019-05-30 00:00:00, 2019-06-27 00:00:00, 2019-07-25 00:00:00, 2019-08-29 00:00:00, 2019-09-26 00:00:00, 2019-10-31 00:00:00, 2019-11-28 00:00:00, 2019-12-26 00:00:00, 2020-01-30 00:00:00, 2020-02-27 00:00:00, 2020-03-26 00:00:00, 2020-04-30 00:00:00, 2020-05-28 00:00:00, 2020-06-25 00:00:00]
```

What I want to do is wherever the dates appear in the data frame list_of_dates in the xl_file, the `Date` be changed to :

```
list_of_dates.index + BDay()
```

However, the contents of the row remain the same.

For example, if the date in `xl_file` is

```
2020-06-25    Thursday
```

That date is also in `list_of_dates` thus what should happen is that date is changed to next `BDay()` which is:

```
2020-06-26    Thursday
```

Without changing the entries in the rest of the row. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
xl_file["Date"] = xl_file["Date"].apply(lambda x: x + BDay() if x in list_of_dates.index else x)
```

EDIT: Just noticed that's an index you're adjusting, so you can do:

```
xl_file.index = xl_file.index.map(lambda x: x + BDay() if x in list_of_dates.index else x)
```